# Identifying the class of an object in Python

Tags: python, object

Please consider the below code:

```
>>> a='hello'
>>> a.__class__
<type 'str'>
>>>
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             print 'I am in init'
...
>>>
>>> o1=Test()
I am in init
>>> o1.__class__
<class '__main__.Test'>
>>>
```

I have the below basic questions:

Q1:From the above code, is it right to say that `a` is an object of class `str`?
Is `str` a class? How can we confirm?

Q2:I understand `o1` is an object of class Test.What does `__main__` denote in `<class '__main__.Test'>`?

Q3:Why is there a *difference* in output of `a.__class__` and `o1.__class` ?

Q4:I also read that even functions in Python are considered objects.So, when i do, `def TestFun():`, i read that `TestFun` is a variable that points to function object. So, `id(TestFun)` should be equal to `id(function object)`.Please suggest how can i retrieve both the id to confirm my understanding.

Comment: Q1. str is a type object... subtle difference... Q2. main is the namespace... Q3. they are different variables ... Q4 yes True, however im not sure what you mean by id(function object)

Comment: `id(function object)` means that you have to execute `id(TestFun)`